# How i can define a missing step from a Groovy project with cucumber?

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

i have one project how is in groovy (not maven structure), and when i review the features is

> ```
> Feature: API Authentication Functionality
>
> @Api @General
> Scenario: I cannot log in to the API with bad credentials
> Given the following users are defined:
>     | USER_EMAIL               | RAW_PASSWORD     |
>   | test@test.reachforce.com | YesGoodPassword! |
>  And I use the username 'test@test.reachforce.com'
>   And I use the password 'UhOhWrongWord!'
>   When I log in to the API
>   Then the response is forbidden
>
>  @Api @General
>   Scenario: I log in to the API
>     Given the following users are defined:
>      | USER_EMAIL               | RAW_PASSWORD     |
>       | test@test.reachforce.com | YesGoodPassword! |
>    And I use the username 'test@test.reachforce.com'
>    And I use the password 'YesGoodPassword!'
>    When I log in to the API
>    Then the response is valid
>    And the response includes a token
> ```

But in the steps this warning appears:

> step the following users are defined does not have a matching glue
>   code

The Steps structure are like: AuthenticationSteps.groovy

And when i run it gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:65)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at com.reachforce.tools.db.DataSourceFactory.<init>(DataSourceFactory.groovy:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
    at com.reachforce.config.ValidationConfig.<init>(ValidationConfig.groovy:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:436)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:680)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.parse(GroovyBackend.java:115)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.loadGlue(GroovyBackend.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \etc\validation\validation.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at com.reachforce.config.ValidationEnvironment.<clinit>(ValidationEnvironment.groovy:10)
... 36 more
```

Any help?

Comment: You should have something like 'Step Definitions' where you define your steps. Looks like that step is not there, or defined in incorrect way.

Comment: I usually declare the Steps definition on my runner package... that when i do it in JAVA... but in groovy i don't have this runner package... where i can find that ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I haven't worked with grrovy + cucumber. You can take a look here to figure out - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/groovy

Comment: The answer is, I think, in your stack trace: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \etc\validation\validation.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your cucumber plugin can not find the step definition classes.

- In your build file, you need to point Cucumber towards the location of your features and step definitions, if your folder structure is any other than what the plugin expects.

Try to have a look at this example for running Cucumber with Groovy step definitions:
[Cucumber-jvm-groovy-example](https://github.com/dkowis/cucumber-jvm-groovy-example)